# Windows phone - C# - Truncating file(s) in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, truncate, windows-phone-7.8

How can I remove 1 character off the end of a certain file in IsolatedStorage?

The code I have so far is:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(appStorage.OpenFile("trailCount", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    writer.Write(1);
}
```

However It doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: What does *However It doesn't seem to work.* mean? Unexpected result? Exception? Absolutely no effect? Try to specify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the last character you could do the following:

```
writer.BaseStream.SetLength(writer.BaseStream.Length - 1);
```

Additionaly, when opening the file, use `FileMode.Open`, otherwise whole file will be truncated.